# Why, in Mono, won't WebRequestMethods.Ftp use the path in my URI?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, mono

Please note the problem described below is with Mono on Fedora.  I tested the same code from Visual Studio and it behaved exactly as expected.  Is this a bug in Mono?

In a browser I can go to `ftp://10.32.70.50/docs` and after entering my username/password I can list the contents of ~username/docs

My ftp client software will either read the root directory (`ftp://10.32.70.50//`) or the top level directory for my login regardless of the relative path following the ip (`ftp://10.32.70.50/docs`).

```
List<string> dirlist = new List<string>();
Uri testuri = new Uri(@"ftp://10.32.70.50:21/doc");
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(testuri); 
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
{
   dirlist.Add((reader.ReadLine()));
}
```

How do I get my code to use the path appended in the URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12850

Work around: append a slash to the end of the path and it will work.

---

This was submitted as a bug in Mono in June 2011:

[Bug 698551 - FtpWebRequest: ListDirectory/ListDirectoryDetails discard the filename](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=698551)

Opened: 2011-06-07 14:35 UTC    Last modified: 2011-06-07 14:35:02 UTC

Comment: good find! I guess this means that the only thing you can do is propose a pull request to fix the bug